# TNS Protocol adapter error while starting SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm facing this problem while working with SQL Developer:

[image]

Status: Failure-Test failed refused the connection with the following error:ORA-12505:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please make sure that your question is complete as described here in more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . You will get quicker and better responses on coomplete questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your database is not configured to listen on a given hostname/port or uses different sid. Use Oracle Net Configuration Assistant to verify that your db is configured correctly